# Ошибка при изменении элемента массива MongoDb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

В моём Azure CosmosDb MongoApi есть JSON с вложенным массивом документов.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a95745df886842904b82f71"),
    "token": "value1",
    "channel": "value2",
    "urls":
    [
        {
            "url": "<url1>", 
            "interval": "<int>"
        },
        {
            "url": "<url2>"
            "interval": "<int>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Я хочу обновить поле "interval" у конкретного элемента массива. Проблема в том, что когда я использую такие решения, как [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453681/mongo-update-array-element-net-driver-2-0) или [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-objects-in-a-documents-array-nested-updating), я получаю следующий экспешн:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command findAndModify failed: Invalid BSON field name 'urls.$.interval'.
```

Тогда я решил сделать запрос через Mongo Shell и получил такую же ошибку:

```
{
    "nMatched": 0,
    "nUpserted": 0,
    "nModified": 0,
    "writeError": 
    {
        "code": 2,
        "errmsg": "Invalid BSON field name 'urls.$.interval'"
    }
}
```

Вот мой C# код:

```
    var filterBuilder = Builders<User>.Filter;
    var filter = filterBuilder.Where(p => p.Token == model.Token && p.Channel == model.Channel && p.Urls.Any( u => u.Url == model.Url));
    var update = Builders<User>.Update.Set(p => p.Urls.ElementAt(-1).interval, 5);
    await _context.Users.FindOneAndUpdateAsync<User>(filter, update);
```

Вот мой запрос в MongoDb shell:

```
db.Users.update( {"urls.interval": 60}, {$set: {"urls.$.interval": 30}} );
```

Вопрос в том, откуда экспешн берётся и как его избежать?

Comment: Не работал с `MongoDb`, но все же... Ваша ошибка говорит, что не находит поле `urls`, может ему не нравиться то, что в оригинале имя с заглавной буквы? Не смог к сожалению найти информации про зависимость к регистру, заодно и узнаю)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за замечаение, зависимость от регистра действительно существует, в моём JSON `urls` написано строчными буквами, это ошибка присутствовала только в вопросе, устранил её.

Answer (score 0):

Получил ответ на английском SO, проблема была в том, что CosmosDB не поддерживает операторы позиционирования, [ссылка на ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49017906/7705850)